# Bokeh RangeTool update on `mouse_released`

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

I have a bokeh layout that consist of a `main_fig` and a `range_selector_fig`. `range_selector_fig` has the widest window possible. I use a RangeTool on `range_selector_fig` to set `main_fig.x_range` in its simplest form as follows,

```
range_tool = RangeTool(x_range=main_fig.x_range)
range_tool.overlay.fill_color = "navy"
range_tool.overlay.fill_alpha = 0.2
range_selector_fig.add_tools(range_tool)
```

However, `main_fig` range update is calculation heavy. Every time `range_tool.x_range` is updated the calculation is triggered continuously as expected causing a laggy and unpleasing figure update. `main_fig` callback assignment is as follows,

```
main_fig.x_range.js_on_change("start", callback)
```

`callback` being an instance of Bokeh `CustomJS` class.

Is there a way to trigger calculations not continuously but just after the mouse button is released while selecting range using `range_tool`?

Comment: Maybe it is worth to open a [Feature Request](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) and ask for a `callback_throttl` like in [`panel`](https://panel.holoviz.org/reference/widgets/DateRangeSlider.html?highlight=callback_throttl). There you can  set the number of milliseconds to pause between callback calls.

Comment: Thanks @mosc9575. I haven't seen a similar request, so I will request asap.